# BigQuery API latency issue

Tags: google-bigquery, google-cloud-storage, google-cloud-sql

I am building an API which reads and spits out data from BigQuery materialized views, as that's where this team stores the data. The latency of this API is around 3 seconds due to BigQuery, which is not ideal.

I was wondering if there is a way to reduce this latency. Caching is already enabled on BQ side, and my API service runs as a spring-boot app on Cloudrun.

Is there am easy way to stream data from BigQuery to CloudSQL and use that for the backend instead?

Answer (score 2):

> I was wondering if there is a way to reduce this latency. Caching is
> already enabled on BQ side, and my API service runs as a spring-boot
> app on Cloudrun.

Beyond optimizing queries, unlikely.

> Is there am easy way to stream data from BigQuery to CloudSQL and use
> that for the backend instead?

Using Cloud SQL to stream BigQuery will not help your response time. You need a data pipeline, such as [Dataflow](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow), to extract, transform and load into Cloud SQL. That takes even more time but is useful, for example, to load a SQL database once per day for future queries.

I do not recommend BiqQuery for transactional queries. That is relatively slow and expensive compared to transactional databases such as MySQL or PostgreSQL (Cloud SQL supports both).

Use BigQuery for data analysis for large/huge datasets. Use SQL databases for fast query response times and transactions.

This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73232353/8016720) has useful information.

Comment: Totally agreed. But unfortunately, BQ is a client limitation and cannot change in the short term. Can dataflow update the data-delta in CloudSQL from BQ? So basically, update the new changes instead of reloading the entire view from BQ?

Comment: @BrownTownCoder - You can write BQ queries for just about anything. Google Cloud Dataflow, which is based on Apache Beam, is a software environment where you write code in Go, Python or Java. Templates are also supported. You might want to look at [Dataflow Prime](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/guides/enable-dataflow-prime) which is serverless.